# Subscription not registered to use namespace "Microsoft.ContainerService" on Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

When creating a Kubernetes Cluster in Azure Portal (referred to as Kubernetes Service some times), I'm getting an error message during rollout which says that the subscription is not registered to use the namespace "Microsoft.ContainerService". There seems to be no error in the setup as the cluster creation request is accepted and the rollout fails after it runs for a few seconds.

Afaik Container services are deprecated and will be shutdown in a few days, so I have no idea why I should need the permission to use this service.

What could this error message mean and how can I create a Kubernetes cluster through Azure portal?

I'm not keen to get started with the CLI since I'm evaluating Azure as an alternative to Google Kubernetes Engine which works like a charm without any unintuitive behaviour, so I won't invest the time to learn a CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about that particular Kubernetes requirement, but the generic resource provider not registered issue can be resolved by just registering that provider.  In the Azure Portal go to Subscriptions -> {your sub} -> Providers and find Microsoft.ContainerService and register it.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be resolved, go to Azure portal and select your subscription and select option "resource providers" and search for "ContainerService" and click on register as shown below.

[image]